# Virtual machines and software activation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, microsoft-office, virtualization

If I create a base image of Windows 7 with Office 2010, do I have to re-activate Office 2010 if I make a clone?

I envision making clones and destroying them at will for testing purposes.  I'm wondering how activation works with cloned virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this many times, and I have not had to re-activate any of them. Since the "hardware" has not changed, it does not look at it as having had enough changes to warrant re-activation.

Answer (score 0):

i created a windows + office virtual machine, activated both products and then cloned it several times without any issues... it worked perfectly for me. VMs for testing are great.
make sure you're ok with licensing and that you activated your products before cloning it -in case you have a limited ammount of activations per license-.